# The difference between int(*function)(int,int) and int*function(int,int)

Tags: c, pointers

I am studying pointers of C and from the book of Deitel I don't get the difference between `int(*function)(int,int)` and `int*function(int,int)` when the function is expressed.

Comment: `int *` is the return type in the second one (Pointer to `int`).. The first is pointer to a function that receives two `int`s and return an `int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rule of thumb for reading types in C:

1. Starting with the identifier you're defining

   - in `int(*function)(int,int)`, "`function` is a..."
   - in `int*function(int,int)`, "`function` is a..."
2. Read to the right until you hit the end of the line or a closing parenthesis

   - in `int(*function)(int,int)`, you hit the parenthesis immediately.
   - in `int*function(int,int)`, "... function that takes two parameters of type `int` and `int`..."
3. Read left from where you started

   - in `int(*function)(int,int)`, "... pointer to ..."
   - in `int*function(int,int)`, "... that returns a pointer to `int`."
4. If you stopped because you hit a closing parenthesis, follow steps 2 & 3 again starting with the closing parenthesis and returning to its corresponding opening parenthesis.

   - in `int(*function)(int,int)` we only read `(*function)` so far, so we continue: "... function that takes parameters of type `int` and `int`..." and backing up, "... that returns an `int`"
   - we hit the end of the line in the other one.

Putting it all together:

`int(*function)(int,int)`

`function` is a pointer to a function that takes two arguments of type `int` and `int` that returns an `int`

`int*function(int,int)`

`function` is a function that takes two arguments of type `int` and `int` and returns a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is a pointer to function which received two `int` arguments and the second one is just a function which returns pointer to int and receives two `int` arguments. It is two really different programming entities. First is data type second is code (function).

Answer (score 2):

The first is a pointer to a function which returns `int`. The second is a declaration of a function which returns a pointer to `int`.